# How can I generate GUIDs in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, guid

I have an excel file with one order on each row, and I want each order to have a unique identifier, so there will be a Unique ID column. Every time I fill a row, I want Excel to automatically populate the Unique ID column for me. I did some research and was pointed in the direction of GUIDs. I found the following code:

```
Function GenGuid() As String
Dim TypeLib As Object
Dim Guid As String
Set TypeLib = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib")
Guid = TypeLib.Guid
' format is {24DD18D4-C902-497F-A64B-28B2FA741661}
Guid = Replace(Guid, "{", "")
Guid = Replace(Guid, "}", "")
Guid = Replace(Guid, "-", "")
GenGuid = Guid
End Function
```

but I am not sure how I can implement it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think your problem is generating a GUID. You have working code for that. You can even get a GUID into any cell by assigning it the formula `=GenGuid()` though it changes on every evaluation of the formula. Your question should rather be: How can I have Excel automatically populate a cell with the result of a VBA function?

Comment: Warning: The above code will add random garbage to the end of the string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556268/why-does-this-vba-print-out-random-garbage

Comment: Don't put this function into a cell as a formula `=GenGuid()` - this will generate all new GUIDs for each row everytime the worksheet recalculates! Instead, use Worksheet events to look for changes to the sheet, and within that you'll need to devise a way to determine if a new/blank row is being edited ("is GUID column blank on this row?"), and if it is then you need to set cell value to the generated GUID (so that it remains static). That's the best way to ensure that once you assign a row a GUID that it keeps the same value forever.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The following Excel expression evaluates to a V4 GUID:

`=CONCATENATE(DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,4294967295),8),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,65535),4),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(16384,20479),4),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(32768,49151),4),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,65535),4),DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,4294967295),8))`

-or (depending on locale setting/decimal and  list separators)-

`=CONCATENATE(DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0;4294967295);8);"-";DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0;65535);4);"-";DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(16384;20479);4);"-";DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(32768;49151);4);"-";DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0;65535);4);DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0;4294967295);8))`

Note that the first character of the third group is always 4 to signify a V4 (pseudo-random number generated) GUID/UUID per RFC 4122 section 4.4.

Also note that the first character of the fourth group is always between 8 and B per the same RFC.

*Standard disclaimer: the resulting GUIDs/UUIDs are not cryptographically strong.*

Edit: remove invisible characters

Comment: This didn't work for me in Excel 2007.  I received a generic there is something wrong with this formula error.

Comment: Works perfectly on Excel for Mac, just have to change `;` to `,`

Comment: Here is the function with the changes this also works in Windows with the ',' change

=CONCATENATE(DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,4294967295),8),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,65535),4),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(16384,20479),4),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(32768,49151),4),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,65535),4),DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,4294967295),8))

Comment: @MirkoAkkov it's not the Mac, it's the Thread.CurrentCulture's System.Globalization.CultureInfo instance that holds a TextInfo object which defines a `ListSeparator` property that determines the character Excel will correctly parse between function arguments in Excel an formula. In Windows this (along with many other settings) can be viewed/changed in the `regional settings` from the control panel.

Comment: How much entropy loss can we expect with this method?

Answer (score 34):

I used the following function in v.2013 excel vba to create a GUID and is working well..

```
Public Function GetGUID() As String 
    GetGUID = Mid$(CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").GUID, 2, 36) 
End Function
```

Comment: Nice piece of code. To eliminate the hyphens you could make it `GetGUID = Replace(Mid$(CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").GUID, 2, 36),"-",vbNullString)`

Comment: It will not work with the latest Windows update. Here is an information how to use this macro in such case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332357/ms-access-vba-error-run-time-error-70-permission-denied

Comment: Since windows update taken out "Scriptlet.TypeLib", try the following:  

Declare Function CoCreateGuid Lib "ole32" (ByRef GUID As Byte) As Long
Public Function GenerateGUID() As String
    Dim ID(0 To 15) As Byte
    Dim N As Long
    Dim GUID As String
    Dim Res As Long
    Res = CoCreateGuid(ID(0))
    
    For N = 0 To 15
        GUID = GUID & IIf(ID(N) < 16, "0", "") & Hex$(ID(N))
        If Len(GUID) = 8 Or Len(GUID) = 13 Or Len(GUID) = 18 Or Len(GUID) = 23 Then
            GUID = GUID & "-"
        End If
    Next N
    GenerateGUID = GUID
End Function

Answer (score 11):

I know this question is answered, but I think the code in question should look something like what's on this page: http://snipplr.com/view/37940/

Haven't tested, but this code seems to tap into the Windows API to get its GUID's - I would try putting that in a public module and typing `=GetGUId()` in an Excel cell to see what I'd get. If it works in VB6 you have a great deal of a good chance it works in VBA as well:

```
Private Type GUID
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(7) As Byte
End Type

Private Declare Function CoCreateGuid Lib "OLE32.DLL" (pGuid As GUID) As Long

Public Function GetGUID() As String
'(c) 2000 Gus Molina

    Dim udtGUID As GUID

    If (CoCreateGuid(udtGUID) = 0) Then

        GetGUID = _
            String(8 - Len(Hex$(udtGUID.Data1)), "0") & Hex$(udtGUID.Data1) & _
            String(4 - Len(Hex$(udtGUID.Data2)), "0") & Hex$(udtGUID.Data2) & _
            String(4 - Len(Hex$(udtGUID.Data3)), "0") & Hex$(udtGUID.Data3) & _
            IIf((udtGUID.Data4(0) < &H10), "0", "") & Hex$(udtGUID.Data4(0)) & _
            IIf((udtGUID.Data4(1) < &H10), "0", "") & Hex$(udtGUID.Data4(1)) & _
            IIf((udtGUID.Data4(2) < &H10), "0", "") & Hex$(udtGUID.Data4(2)) & _
            IIf((udtGUID.Data4(3) < &H10), "0", "") & Hex$(udtGUID.Data4(3)) & _
            IIf((udtGUID.Data4(4) < &H10), "0", "") & Hex$(udtGUID.Data4(4)) & _
            IIf((udtGUID.Data4(5) < &H10), "0", "") & Hex$(udtGUID.Data4(5)) & _
            IIf((udtGUID.Data4(6) < &H10), "0", "") & Hex$(udtGUID.Data4(6)) & _
            IIf((udtGUID.Data4(7) < &H10), "0", "") & Hex$(udtGUID.Data4(7))
    End If

End Function
```

Thanks Gus Molina!

If this code works (which I don't doubt), I think you'd get a new set of GUID's whenever the function gets evaluated, which means everytime the sheet gets calculated - when you're saving the workbook, for example. Make sure to copy-pastespecial-values if you need the GUID's for later use... which is somewhat likely.

Comment: Anyone able to add comments to that code to explain what it's doing?

Comment: @EmilyBeth it invokes `CoCreateGuid` from OLE32.DLL, stores the result in a user-defined type, then left-pads each part with 0s and converts them into hex strings. `Data1 As Long` holds the first 4 bytes, `Data2` and `Data3 As Integer` hold the next 4 bytes, then `Data4` holds the remaining 8 bytes. A GUID is really just a very, very large number stored across 16 bytes, with specific parts.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, sir, is there any probability of collision while GUID created using CoCreateGuid method?

Comment: @KamalBharakhda it's probably what the Scripting library is invoking under the hood anyway, and it's OS-level. I doubt there's any risk of collisions there.

Answer (score 6):

I found pretty solution here:
http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualutils.aspx?action=gotomsg&tid=751237&msg=8634441

```
Option Explicit

Private Type GUID
  Data1 As Long
  Data2 As Integer
  Data3 As Integer
  Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type
Private Declare Function CoCreateGuid Lib "ole32" (pguid As GUID) As Long
Private Declare Function StringFromGUID2 Lib "ole32" ( _
  rguid As GUID, ByVal lpsz As Long, ByVal cchMax As Long) As Long

Public Function CreateGUID() As String
  Dim NewGUID As GUID
  CoCreateGuid NewGUID
  CreateGUID = Space$(38)
  StringFromGUID2 NewGUID, StrPtr(CreateGUID), 39
End Function
```

Answer (score 5):

A VBA approach based on generating random numbers using the `Rnd()` function, and not on external API calls or `Scriptlet.TypeLib`:

```
Public Function CreateGUID() As String
    Do While Len(CreateGUID) < 32
        If Len(CreateGUID) = 16 Then
            '17th character holds version information
            CreateGUID = CreateGUID & Hex$(8 + CInt(Rnd * 3))
        End If
        CreateGUID = CreateGUID & Hex$(CInt(Rnd * 15))
    Loop
    CreateGUID = "{" & Mid(CreateGUID, 1, 8) & "-" & Mid(CreateGUID, 9, 4) & "-" & Mid(CreateGUID, 13, 4) & "-" & Mid(CreateGUID, 17, 4) & "-" & Mid(CreateGUID, 21, 12) & "}"
End Function
```

This essentially is a VBA implementation of NekojiruSou's answer (it also generates a v4 GUID), and carries the same limitations, but will work in VBA and might be easier to implement.

Note that you can omit the last line to not return the dashes and curly braces in the result.

Answer (score 4):

This is based on a [javascript implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2117523/6302131).

```
Private Function getGUID() As String
  Call Randomize 'Ensure random GUID generated
  getGUID = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  getGUID = Replace(getGUID, "y", Hex(Rnd() And &H3 Or &H8))
  Dim i As Long: For i = 1 To 30
    getGUID = Replace(getGUID, "x", Hex$(Int(Rnd() * 16)), 1, 1)
  Next
End Function
```

Comment: i have tested this method results in http://guid.us/Test/GUID and turns out it gives invalid guid output.

Comment: @AliSafari Thanks for the information. You were absolutely correct, Something I didn't catch was that clng doesn't round down like in other languages! Fixed now :)

Comment: @Sancam you did a good job!

Answer (score 2):

Same same for *german* Excel version:

```
=VERKETTEN(DEZINHEX(ZUFALLSBEREICH(0;4294967295);8);"-";DEZINHEX(ZUFALLSBEREICH(0;65535);4);"-";DEZINHEX(ZUFALLSBEREICH(16384;20479);4);"-";DEZINHEX(ZUFALLSBEREICH(32768;49151);4);"-";DEZINHEX(ZUFALLSBEREICH(0;65535);4);DEZINHEX(ZUFALLSBEREICH(0;4294967295);8))
```

Comment: The *version* is actually the same. It's the local settings that determine what the function aliases are and what character delimits function arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Since windows update taken out "Scriptlet.TypeLib", try the following:

```
Declare Function CoCreateGuid Lib "ole32" (ByRef GUID As Byte) As Long
Public Function GenerateGUID() As String
    Dim ID(0 To 15) As Byte
    Dim N As Long
    Dim GUID As String
    Dim Res As Long
    Res = CoCreateGuid(ID(0))

    For N = 0 To 15
        GUID = GUID & IIf(ID(N) < 16, "0", "") & Hex$(ID(N))
        If Len(GUID) = 8 Or Len(GUID) = 13 Or Len(GUID) = 18 Or Len(GUID) = 23 Then
            GUID = GUID & "-"
        End If
    Next N
    GenerateGUID = GUID
End Function
```

Alternatively,

if you are connecting to SQL Server 2008 or higher, try to use the SQL NEWID() function instead.

Comment: Note that, if you're using Access, not Excel, you can use `Application.StringFromGUID(ID)` to convert the GUID to a string. Saves you from iterating over it yourself, and creates a GUID in a format that you can easily convert back to bytes using `Application.GuidFromString`.

Answer (score 2):

I created a VBA function that works both on mac and windows:

https://github.com/Martin-Carlsson/Business-Intelligence-Goodies/blob/master/Excel/GenerateGiud/GenerateGiud.bas

```
'Generates a guid, works on both mac and windows 
Function Guid() As String
    Guid = RandomHex(3) + "-" + _
        RandomHex(2) + "-" + _
        RandomHex(2) + "-" + _
        RandomHex(2) + "-" + _
        RandomHex(6)
End Function

'From: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/301472-need-help-generate-hexadecimal-codes-randomly.html#post1479527
Private Function RandomHex(lngCharLength As Long)
    Dim i As Long
    Randomize
    For i = 1 To lngCharLength
        RandomHex = RandomHex & Right$("0" & Hex(Rnd() * 256), 2)
    Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into problems using CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib") in some vba code.

So based on NekojiruSou excel functions wrote the following which should work without any specific excel functions.  This can be used to develop a user defined function in excel.

```
Public Function Get_NewGUID() As String
    'Returns GUID as string 36 characters long

    Randomize

    Dim r1a As Long
    Dim r1b As Long
    Dim r2 As Long
    Dim r3 As Long
    Dim r4 As Long
    Dim r5a As Long
    Dim r5b As Long
    Dim r5c As Long

    'randomValue = CInt(Math.Floor((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd())) + lowerbound
    r1a = RandomBetween(0, 65535)
    r1b = RandomBetween(0, 65535)
    r2 = RandomBetween(0, 65535)
    r3 = RandomBetween(16384, 20479)
    r4 = RandomBetween(32768, 49151)
    r5a = RandomBetween(0, 65535)
    r5b = RandomBetween(0, 65535)
    r5c = RandomBetween(0, 65535)

    Get_NewGUID = (PadHex(r1a, 4) & PadHex(r1b, 4) & "-" & PadHex(r2, 4) & "-" & PadHex(r3, 4) & "-" & PadHex(r4, 4) & "-" & PadHex(r5a, 4) & PadHex(r5b, 4) & PadHex(r5c, 4))

End Function

Public Function Floor(ByVal X As Double, Optional ByVal Factor As Double = 1) As Double
    'From: http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5031
    ' X is the value you want to round
    ' Factor is the multiple to which you want to round
        Floor = Int(X / Factor) * Factor
End Function

Public Function RandomBetween(ByVal StartRange As Long, ByVal EndRange As Long) As Long
    'Based on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7s023d2(v=vs.90).aspx
    '         randomValue = CInt(Math.Floor((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd())) + lowerbound
        RandomBetween = CLng(Floor((EndRange - StartRange + 1) * Rnd())) + StartRange
End Function

Public Function PadLeft(text As Variant, totalLength As Integer, padCharacter As String) As String
    'Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060347/any-method-equivalent-to-padleft-padright
    ' with a little more checking of inputs

    Dim s As String
    Dim inputLength As Integer
    s = CStr(text)
    inputLength = Len(s)

    If padCharacter = "" Then
        padCharacter = " "
    ElseIf Len(padCharacter) > 1 Then
        padCharacter = Left(padCharacter, 1)
    End If

    If inputLength < totalLength Then
        PadLeft = String(totalLength - inputLength, padCharacter) & s
    Else
        PadLeft = s
    End If

End Function

Public Function PadHex(number As Long, length As Integer) As String
    PadHex = PadLeft(Hex(number), 4, "0")
End Function
```

Comment: recently ran into problems using the CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib") method as well.  Permission denied?

Answer (score 1):

For generating random guids using just the `Rnd()` function, not using any libraries or APIs, the simplest I can think of is this:

```
' UUID Version 4 (random)
Function GetUUID4()

    Dim guid As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    
    guid = ""
    Randomize
    
    For i = 0 To 31
        ' random digit 0..15
        r = Rnd() * 15

        ' add dash separators
        If (i = 8) Or (i = 12) Or (i = 16) Or (i = 20) Then guid = guid & "-"

        ' uuid4 version info in 12th and 16th digits
        If (i = 12) Then r = 4
        If (i = 16) Then r = (r And 3 Or 8)

        ' add as hex digit
        guid = guid & Hex(r)
    Next i

    GetUUID4 = guid
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get 36 base `GUID` in Excel you have to add some small vba function, but keep in mind this code can also work in other vab context like **Microsoft Access**.

Flow the steps:

1. Open Excel go to developer mode tab.
2. Click on Visual Basic Button.
3. Create a Model and past the code below.

```vb
Function GUID$(Optional lowercase As Boolean, Optional parens As Boolean)
    Dim k&, h$
    GUID = Space(36)
    For k = 1 To Len(GUID)
        Randomize
        Select Case k
            Case 9, 14, 19, 24: h = "-"
            Case 15:            h = "4"
            Case 20:            h = Hex(Rnd * 3 + 8)
            Case Else:          h = Hex(Rnd * 15)
        End Select
        Mid$(GUID, k, 1) = h
    Next
    If lowercase Then GUID = LCase$(GUID)
    If parens Then GUID = "{" & GUID & "}"
End Function
```

**Note:**

You can fore the UUID to have only lowrcase chars by passing `True` to the first parameter. Also you're able to add braces `{}` by passing `True` to the second parameter, but keep in mind that the char cout will be 38.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting records into a database you can use this way to make a GUID.

It is probably the most simplest and easiest way to implement as you don't need a complex `VBA` function as you use the built in SQL function.

The statement uses `NewID()`,

The syntax is as follows,

```
INSERT INTO table_name (ID,Column1,Column2,Column3)
VALUES (NewID(),value1,value2,value3)
```

In `VBA` syntax it is as follows,

```
strSql = "INSERT INTO table_name " _
       & "(ID,Column1,Column2,Column3) " _
       & "VALUES (NewID(),value1,value2,value3)"
```

And if you need to concatenate values, just treat it as a string and concatenate as you would normally for a SQL statement,

```
strSql = "INSERT INTO table_name " _
       & "(ID,Column1,Column2,Column3) " _
       & "VALUES (" & "NewID()" & "," & "value1" & "," & "value2" & "," & "value3" & ")"
```

Comment: This is a great method, but not if you need to use the guid within VBA first, before uploading (I.E inserting the same GUID across multiple tables)

Comment: @BrendanGooden, I see now. The OP is not inserting into a database. I will update my answer to show that. Thanks.

Answer (score -6):

```
Function funGetGuid() As String

    Const URL As String = "http://www.guidgen.com/"
    Const strMask As String = "value="

    Dim l As Long
    Dim txt As String

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        txt = .responseText
    End With

    Do
        l = InStr(l + 1, txt, strMask)
        If l = 0 Then Exit Do
        funGetGuid = Mid$(txt, l + Len(strMask) + 1, 36)
    Loop

End Function
```

Comment: In my opinion making a remote request just to generate a GUID is not an appropriate method.