# always print out 6 digits following specific string

Tags: vba, excel, string-length

I have many strings with the name "TL-" followed by 6 digits (ie TL-000456, TL-000598). Sometimes it will print out having fewer than 6 digits (ie TL-09872, TL-345, TL-02).

**I want my code to add a zero after the "TL-" until it contains 6 digits.**

```
Start:           Output:
TL-000456   ->   TL-000456
TL-000598   ->   TL-000598
TL-09872    ->   TL-009872
TL-345      ->   TL-000345
TL-02       ->   TL-000002
```

If possible, I would like it to do this so that even if a space is included in the string (ie "TL - ", "TL -"), 6 digits would always be grabbed.

```
TL - 987    ->   TL-000987
TL- 839     ->   TL-000839
```

I have a function in my code which trims the "TL" values to get everything before a semicolon or comma so ideally the code would go in there. Thoughts?

**CURRENT ATTEMPTS GIVEN COMMENTS:**

Code gets values from under the header "CUTTING TOOL" in the ws (worksheet) and prints it to the StartSht (workbook with code)

(1) Returns error on `Trim` line saying in valid procedure or argument

```
With WB
  For Each ws In .Worksheets

Dim sIn, sOut As String
    'find CUTTING TOOL on the source sheet
    If Not ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING TOOL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
    Set hc = ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING TOOL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
        Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0), "SplitMe")
        If dict.count > 0 Then
        'add the values to the workbook, column 3
            Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)


            'trim values **implement new code here**
            With StartSht
                Trim (Left(sIn, InStr(1, sIn, "-", vbTextCompare) - 1)) & "-" & Right("000000" & Trim(Right(sIn, Len(sIn) - InStr(1, sIn, "-", vbTextCompare))), 6)
            End With
```

(2) Runs fully but does not change the values

```
With WB
  For Each ws In .Worksheets
        'find CUTTING TOOL on the source sheet
        If Not ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING TOOL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
        Set hc = ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING TOOL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
            Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0), "SplitMe")
            If dict.count > 0 Then
            'add the values to the master list, column 3
                Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)

                Dim str As String, ret As String, tmp As String, j As Integer
                With StartSht
                For j = 1 To Len(str)
                    tmp = Mid(str, j, 1)
                    If IsNumeric(tmp) Then ret = ret + tmp
                Next j

                For j = Len(ret) + 1 To 6
                    ret = "0" & ret
                Next

                Debug.Print ret


                End With
```

---

StartSht Excel document looks like this

```
      A            B                C                  D
1    TDS        HOLDER        CUTTING TOOL        File Name
2   TDS-1         H1            TL-000289          TDS-1.xlsx
3   TDS-2         H2            TL-000274          TDS-2.xlsx
4   TDS-3         H3            TL-0002            TDS-3.xlsx
5   TDS-4         H4            TL-0343            TDS-4.xlsx
```

after the "CUTTING TOOL" code I have below, it just looks like the output below the code because that is the first section I grab information for

CODE:

```
            With WB
                For Each ws In .Worksheets
                'find CUTTING TOOL on the source sheet
                If Not ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING TOOL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                Set hc = ws.Range("A1:M15").Find(What:="CUTTING TOOL", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
                    Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0), "SplitMe")
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                    'add the values to the master list, column 3
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
```

output of StartSht:

```
      A            B                C                  D
1    TDS        HOLDER        CUTTING TOOL        File Name
2                              TL-000289          
3                              TL-000274          
4                              TL-0002            
5                              TL-0343
```

I want to add a line str = StartSht.Range(''set correct range here'') and then code to make the StartSht look like this

```
      A            B                C                  D
1    TDS        HOLDER        CUTTING TOOL        File Name
2                              TL-000289          
3                              TL-000274          
4                              TL-000002            
5                              TL-000343
```

Comment: When using a With statement, you have to use a period before every statement you want associated with the With. See the examples in this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on Orphid's anwswer to include the 6 digits:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim str as string, ret as string, tmp as string, i as integer, j as integer

    for j = 2 to StartSht.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row            
        ret = ""
        str = StartSht.Range("C" & j).Value
            for i = 1 to len(str)
                  tmp = mid(str, i, 1)
                  if IsNumeric(tmp) then ret = ret + tmp
            next i

            For i = Len(ret) + 1 To 6
                ret = "0" & ret
            Next
            ret = "TL-" & ret
            StartSht.Range("C" & j).Value = ret
    next j
End Sub
```

This is going to write 'ret' in column B beside the original. The sheet you are working on needs to be active when this runs because as you can see I didn't specify which Sheet was to be used. You can do that yourself if it's necessary. I assumed it only needed to be done on 1 worksheet of 1 workbook for this. Let me know if i was wrong.

Comment: If I am trying to do this for tens of thousands of "TL" strings, what would I put in for `str` in that situation? @DavidGM I haved edited my code above to show a function where it trims the value to grab everything before a semicolon or comma. Ideally, I would like to put this restriction of code in that function. Would that work well?

Comment: I have added the section of code I am trying to implement this idea in. Could you take a look at it and tell me what I may be doing wrong or how to implement your code with mine? I ran it with your code and no errors kick back but the values do not change to six digits @DavidGM

Comment: If they don't change, what happens? Does it extract the numbers successfully? If you comment out the second loop, it doesn't change anything? Please post what the debug.print writes.

Comment: OH the problem is that you,re not assigning anything to the values we use. When we say str for example, you are supposed to assign a value to that. str is supposed to be a "T - 2314" like string, that you take either from your sheet or from an existing variable. In your code, you dim str, and then you use it right away. It doesn't contain anything yet. If you want to assign a value from a sheet that has a long column with many values, for example, you could loop on all those cells and have something like str = ws.range('the cell you're at') before using it.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you! So, like a few lines above it in my code, I am trying to set str to be `str = StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1))` so it gets the current column I am in and goes up to where the cell originally started.. but the error is type mismatch and when I try others I get an invalid range error @davidgm

Comment: First off, what is StartSht? Is it the active sheet at the moment? is it supposed to be the same as ws (which you're looping over)? Second, your statement makes no sense. str = something. not str = something, something else. Third, what are you planning to do with the dictionnary? I am personally not good with those so I won't be able to offer much help if it's important.

Comment: If you tell me exactly how your sheet looks, how many sheets it has, where you want to write the data and in which sheets, where the values you want to convert are placed, I'll write it all for you because using your code is very difficult right now. Eventually you'll get better and look over this code and understand what I mean ;)

Comment: So my code has a main workbook with all of the code in it, StartSht. The code opens a designated folder and loops through all the files, ws is all of the Sheets in that file. The code grabes the TL values from under the header "CUTTING TOOL". The dictionary grabs those values from the last taken row in a column up to the header and puts them into column C of the StartSht. What I want to do is, after all that is done, look into column C of the StartSht, and if length of digits following "TL-" is less than six, add zeros after "TL-" until it is six digits long @DavidGM

Comment: So this code you are helping me work on should not have anything to do with the rest of my code, simply with the Excel document, StartSht, which holds a column of values that I want to change with the code you are helping me work on.

Comment: Haha I am sure you're right! I'm very new to VBA so I know my code is rough to say the least. Okay I will add that to the question. Just give me a few minutes and it'll be updated! Thank you @DavidGM

Comment: Is there any chance I could email it to you? My browser is too out of date to upload images anymore and I do not have permission to update it. Or I could upload them on another site and post a link if you're able to view it that way @davidgm

Comment: OK. I suggest separating the code you have, that works, with the one that doesn't. Start a different sub for the one that doesn't and call it from the first one. If I understand correctly, all you want to do is to change StartSht. Replace values with others with what we wrote. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I would rather not open yours since I am at work. I am permitted to use stack overflow because they know I use it to get some help sometimes but I wouldn't be at ease working directly in your workbook, sorry.

Comment: completely understandable. I am doing the same at work. What I ultimately need help with is how to set that range I think. Otherwise I cannot see a reason why it would work. In my code I have each sheet, ws - worksheets in opening files, StartSht - workbook with code that info prints to, WB - folder to search through, specifically named and I jump back and forth between them all throughout my code with no issues. I was hoping to just use that line `str = StartSht.Range(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1).End(xlUp)` but with an appropriate range to fix the issue

Comment: I have edited my question to try to give you a better picture @davidgm
after the "-------------------" in the question

Comment: I edited my answer. I believe it would work. Good edits to your question, by the way. And sorry if this is taking so long! haha. You cannot assign a range to a string. This is what you are trying to do with that statement. instead, I cycle through the cells in StartSht going from C2 to the last entry in C2, and assign a single cell's value at a time to str. That way it can be processed.

Comment: No thank you for helping me out for so long! Okay so it runs but if, for example, the first three cells should say, as in my example, TL-000289,TL-000274, and TL- 0002, it outputs in every row of column C: 0002890002740002. So the "TL-" needs to be added back in and an offset of offset(1,0) should take place somewhere, but the added 0s still do not occur... any ideas? @davidgm

Comment: I added something small (ret = "") to reset it between every row and the "TL" which i had missed. I'd like to see your code though because mine should not do what you described - unless the first few were fine and it SEEMEDlike they were the same because it just piled on (since I wasn't resetting ret).

Comment: Heading home, I'll answer your next questions tomorrow if you haven't fixed it. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @davidgm . This works beautifully. I was wondering if you'd help me with some exceptions. Would it be best to start a new question for that?

Comment: Agreed. Here is my new question if you wouldn't mind taking a look at it. Thank you again for all of your help! @DavidGM http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164466/vba-troubleshooting-with-find-method

Answer (score 3):

There is a way using an excel formula:

```
="TL-" & TEXT(TRIM(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1,1))),"000000")
```

Comment: would this work even if TL-09828 was TL- 09828 or TL - 09828? (differing amount of spaces following "TL")

Comment: I think so - I used `TRIM` for that reason. Why not try it and see if you get the results you expect?

Comment: Okay I'll try that @AlexP . My issue is trying to figure out the range though. I would use your excel formula in order to create a macro to figure out the VBA code for it but I cannot figure out how to get it to grab only the items in column C

Comment: If your values are in column C then can you add the formula to `D1` and then drag it down? This would give you the desired output without the need for VBA and a loop etc...

Comment: this is definitely a great method and very good to know but unfortuantely I need to use VBA to have this all automated. Also it would need to overwrite the values in column C instead of adding a new column

Answer (score 2):

What have you tried so far? Do you have any code to show us?

This should be a starting point, you'll need to strip out spaces and loop through the whole file of course.

```
Public Sub PaddingTest()
Dim PaddingArray() As String
Dim PaddingVar As String
PaddingArray() = Split(Range("A1").Value, "-", 2, vbTextCompare)
PaddingVar = PaddingArray(1)
While Len(PaddingVar) < 6
    PaddingVar = "0" & PaddingVar
Wend
Range("A2").Value = PaddingArray(0) & "-" & PaddingVar
End Sub
```

[msdn.microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for usage of Split command

Answer (score 1):

For extracting the number, it sounds like what you want is a regular expression similar to \d{1,6}. However, I've never really enjoyed working regex in VBA, so another way of extracting the number is:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim str as string, ret as string, tmp as string, i as integer
    str = "T- 087652" 
    for i = 1 to len(str) 'vba strings are 1-indexed
        tmp = mid(str, i, 1) 'get the character at position i
        if IsNumeric(tmp) then ret = ret + temp 'if numeric, add to the return value
    next i
    debug.print ret 'print the resulting number to the console. To convert to a number, simply assign to a variable typed as "long"
End Sub
```

What this does is a simple forward loop through the string, extracting every character which `IsNumeric`. It should ignore whitespace wherever it occurs in the string, but they shouldn't be more than one whole number per string.

For formatting the number, you probably just want to [pad the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060347/any-method-equivalent-to-padleft-padright).

Comment: Added on to your answer. Good solution!

Comment: Yep, forgot to mention that. Have edited in a line to point to how to pad a string, but your solution is just as logical, given the problem :-).

Comment: I have added the section of code I am trying to implement this idea in. Could you take a look at it and tell me what I may be doing wrong or how to implement your code with mine? I am confused on how to mesh the two together @Orphid

Answer (score 1):

Put this in a new module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function getDigits(strInput As String) As String

    Dim strOutput As String
    Dim strCharacter As String
    Dim i As Integer

    strOutput = ""

    For i = 1 To Len(strInput)
        strCharacter = Mid(strInput, i, 1)
        If strCharacter >= "0" And strCharacter <= "9" Then
            strOutput = strOutput & strCharacter
        End If
    Next

    getDigits = strOutput

End Function

Public Function addZeros(strInput As String) As String

    Dim intCurrentLength As Integer
    Dim strNumber As String
    Dim i As Integer

    strNumber = getDigits(strInput)
    intCurrentLength = Len(strNumber)

    If intCurrentLength < 6 Then

        For i = 1 To 6 - intCurrentLength
            strNumber = "0" & strNumber
        Next i

    End If

    addZeros = "TL-" & strNumber

End Function
```

Then just run addZeros([your string here]) to convert to the required format.

---

(for user4888 in the comments of this question; an example of how to check whether 'TL' is in a string. This checks cells A1 to A10, and populates a 1 or a 0 in the corresponding cell in column B depending on whether there is a 'TL' in the cell)

```
Private Sub TLcheck()

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

    For i = 1 To 10
        ws.Cells(i, 2) = InStr(1, ws.Cells(i, 1), "TL")
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily long, but hey. If it works, it works!

Comment: Yep, I definitely wasn't thinking about optimization here, it was more of a stream-of-consciousness effort. Possibly has the advantage of being easy to understand by someone new to VBA though!

Comment: @MarkButler definitely easy to understand! thank you for your answer. Would you mind taking a look at my code that I posted in the question and helping me to figure out where/how to implement the addZeros function within the code?

Comment: Sure, I'll set up a spreadsheet now and then update the answer

Comment: @user4888, have you solved this yet? If not, I'll have a look if you upload a version of your spreadsheet. I've upvoted Alex P's answer though; it's an easy thing to do without any VBA.

Comment: @MarkButler I have not solved this yet. I haved added to the question a rough idea of what the spreadsheet, what all the information is printed to which also holds the code, looks like. Unfortunately my browser will not let me upload images at this time. I'd gladly email you a rendering or post it somewhere and attach a link if either of those work for you. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @MarkButler it does work now but I am working on exceptions like an if statement to only do the code (that is the accepted answer by DavidGM) if the cell has the "TL-" in it. For example, there are some random cells with something like COB297 and I need that to be skipped over. I think it would be best for me to post a new question for that, correct?

Comment: That's quite a simple task, I'll just comment something here

Comment: To check if a string has 'TL' in it, we can use

    InStr(1, [syour string], "TL")

See my update to this answer for an example.

Comment: that is good to know, thank you. My problem is only performing the code on cells that do have "TL" in it. I have added a new question to make it clearer if you wouldn't mind taking a look at it @MarkButler http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164466/vba-troubleshooting-with-find-method

Comment: The code I have provided above should work for this? Just wrap the parts of the code where the text is being changed in this: IF InStr(1, [theInputString], "TL") > 0 THEN ..... code goes here ...... END IF

Comment: Obviously [theInputString] must be changed with whatever your string variable is; you have used str thus far.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one liner. I am grabbing the data before and after the hypen, trimming them to remove spaces, and adding the hyphen and extra 0's.

```
Sub splitAddZeros()
    Dim sIn, sOut As String

    sIn = "TL - 987"

    out = Trim(Left(sIn, InStr(1, sIn, "-", vbTextCompare) - 1)) & "-" & Right("000000" & Trim(Right(sIn, Len(sIn) - InStr(1, sIn, "-", vbTextCompare))), 6)

    Debug.Print out
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice. Here is your first +1 on Stack overflow ;)

Comment: I am trying to do this for tens of thousands of "TL" strings. what would I put in for `sIn` in that situation? @wyattshipman

Comment: You wouldn't. It is an example. In reality you'd do a loop over your input values e.g. `for each cell in Range("A1:A100000")...cell.offset(0, 1) = Trim...next cell`

Comment: I have added code to my original question so it is easier to walk through with me. I am adding the code into a for loop and am unsure how to correctly input it. Any advice? @AlexP

Comment: I have added code to the original question trying out a mesh of your code with mine but it kicks back an error... any idea where I am going wrong? @wyattshipman

Comment: The problem is probably that you aren't assigning any value to sIn. @AlexP mentioned how to apply this. In you code, you are looping though you sheets, but you only need to loop through the strings you want  to convert. You could activate the StartSheet and then do a For Each loop to move through the cells with strings to format and let each cell value = sIn in the loop.