# VBA - troubleshooting with .Find method

Tags: vba, excel, find

I am using a .Find method to find cells in a row that contain part of the value "TL" and "CT". What the code currently does is look in every row in column C, trims any variation of "TL-" (ie "TL- ", "TL - ", "TL -") and then limits the numbers after it to only have 6 numbers. Example: if it has 5 numbers, it will add a 0 after the "TL-", if it has 4 numbers, it will add 2 0s after the "TL-" etc.

I have other values in the cells so **what it does now** is change all the values to do the above method (as shown below)

```
Start:         Output:
TL-000872  ->  TL-000872
TL-0786    ->  TL-000786
CT-74      ->  TL-000074
GS8; 278K  ->  TL-008278
```

**What I need it to do** is the code that is working but only on cells that contain some "TL" value, do the same code but with only 4 numbers on cells that contain some "CT" value, and skip over (leave as is) anything else.

```
Start:         Output:
TL-000872  ->  TL-000872
TL-0786    ->  TL-000786
CT-74      ->  CT-0074
GS8; 278K  ->  GS8; 278K
```

My .Find method is definitely not working. I believe that is the main problem; It is not correctly finding the cells with "TL" and "CT". Any suggestions?

NOTE: StartSht is the workbook with the code where all of the values being changed exist.

```
Dim str As String, ret As String, tmp As String, j As Integer, k As Integer

If Not StartSht.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Find(What:="TL", LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
For k = 2 To StartSht.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row
    ret = ""
    str = StartSht.Range("C" & k).Value
        For j = 1 To Len(str)
            tmp = Mid(str, j, 1)
            If IsNumeric(tmp) Then ret = ret + tmp
        Next j

        For j = Len(ret) + 1 To 6
            ret = "0" & ret
        Next
        ret = "TL-" & ret
        StartSht.Range("C" & k).Value = ret

        Next k

ElseIf Not StartSht.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Find(What:="CT", LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
For k = 2 To StartSht.Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row
    ret = ""
    str = StartSht.Range("C" & k).Value
        For j = 1 To Len(str)
            tmp = Mid(str, j, 1)
            If IsNumeric(tmp) Then ret = ret + tmp
        Next j

        For j = Len(ret) + 1 To 4
            ret = "0" & ret
        Next
        ret = "CT-" & ret
        StartSht.Range("C" & k).Value = ret

Next k

Else

End If
```

---

**EDIT:**

The code currently takes a TL that has LESS than 6 numbers following the "TL-" and adds a 0 immediately following "TL-" until the length is six. (ie TL-0098 -> TL-000098, two 0s are added). I need it to also catch if TL has MORE than 6 numbers and delete the zeros immediately following "TL-"  until the length is six
Easier code might be to simply delete any number following the "-" until the length is six.

EXAMPLE:

```
TL-0009999   ->  delete one 0  -> TL-009999
TL-0948398   ->  delete one 0  -> TL-948398
TL-00000008  ->  delete two 0s -> TL-000008
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your above code with the below one.

Updated Code:

```VBA
Dim str As String, ret As String, tmp As String, j As Integer, k As Integer

For k = 2 To Sheets("Test").Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row
        ret = ""
        str = Sheets("Test").Range("C" & k).Value

        If InStr(str, "TL") > 0 Then
            For j = 1 To Len(str)
                tmp = Mid(str, j, 1)
                If IsNumeric(tmp) Then
                    ret = ret + tmp
                ElseIf j > 5 And tmp = "T" Then
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next j

            For j = Len(ret) + 1 To 6
                ret = "0" & ret
            Next j

            If Len(ret) > 6 Then
                Debug.Print Len(ret)
                For j = Len(ret) To 7 Step -1
                If Mid(ret, 1, 1) = "0" Then
                    ret = Right(ret, j - 1)
                End If
                Next j
            End If

            ret = "TL-" & ret
            Sheets("Test").Range("C" & k).Value = ret
        ElseIf InStr(str, "CT") Then
            For j = 1 To Len(str)
                tmp = Mid(str, j, 1)
                If IsNumeric(tmp) Then ret = ret + tmp
            Next j

            For j = Len(ret) + 1 To 4
                ret = "0" & ret
            Next
            ret = "CT-" & ret
            Sheets("Test").Range("C" & k).Value = ret
        End If

      Next k
```

Comment: works beautifully thank you! what exactly does tmp = Mid(str, j, 1) do? @prabukrishna

Comment: also, one more troubleshooting issue... is there a way to make it that if TL has MORE that 6 numbers following it, it DELETES the zero / zeros immediately following the "TL-"? I didn't know if that was a simple few lines or a more complex issue @PrabuKrishna

Comment: i didn't understand your second query, can you please expalin with the sample data?

Comment: I have added an EDIT section to the bottom of my original question to better explain with data @Prabukrishna

Comment: Thank you so very much for your beautiful code and explanation. Sorry if I am asking too much but even if you could give me a hint of how to do this, sometimes it will contain "TL-000892 TL-000980" in one cell and I just want it to grab the first section. I cannot specify by spaces because sometimes TL looks like "TL - ", could I have it that if it runs into a second "TL" it would ignore that and everything after it? @Prabukrishna

Comment: after trying this out with more files, if a cell contains `TL-000798 #3 1/2" Holder` it will output `TL-798312` . Do you know how I might alter the code so that it will not grab all of these numbers? I was thinking it could somehow fix any space issues around "TL-" (ie `TL -` -> `TL-` , `TL - ` -> `TL-`, ` TL -` ->`TL-` etc) and then if there is a space, " ", ignore everything after that... do you know a way to do this? @Prabukrishna

Comment: In the below line of code replcae the "T" with " " this                          ElseIf j > 5 And tmp = "T" Then