# Only replace at MID location in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to use the replace function to only replace at the exact location of the `MID` and not all occurences in the cell.
Ex. I want to replace the `###` in `+++++###****###` at position six (1st occurence) and not the second one.

```
For Each c In .Columns(3).Cells
    If c.Value = "" Then
    Else
    Do While Len(c.Value) < 20
         c.Value = c.Value & " "
    Loop
    transNum = Mid(c.Value, 6, 3)
    c.Value = Replace(c.Value, Mid(c.Value, 6, 3), "")
    c.Value = "0" & transNum & c.Value
    End If
    y.Sheets(1).Range("E" & c.Row) = y.Sheets(1).Range("E" & c.Row) & c.Value
Next c
```

Answer (score 5):

`Mid` is both a statement and a function. Use the statement version to do what you want. `Mid` is in help separately as both a statement and as a function.

```
C = "CatDog"
Mid(C, 2) = "Fr"
MsgBox C
```

> **Mid Statement**
>
> Replaces a specified number of characters in a Variant (String)
>   variable with characters from another string.
>
> Syntax
>
> Mid(stringvar, start[, length]) = string
>
> The `Mid` **statement** syntax has these parts:
>
> **stringvar** Required. Name of string variable to
>   modify.  start Required; Variant (Long). Character position in
>   **stringvar** where the replacement of text begins.
>
> **length** Optional;
>   Variant (Long). Number of characters to replace. If omitted, all of
>   string is used.
>
> **string** Required. String expression that replaces part
>   of stringvar.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> The number of characters replaced is always less than or equal to the
>   number of characters in stringvar.
>
> Note   Use the `MidB` statement with byte data contained in a string. In
>   the `MidB` statement, start specifies the byte position within stringvar
>   where replacement begins and length specifies the numbers of bytes to
>   replace.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if it will work directly:

```
Mid(c.Value, 6, 3) = ""
```

**Update**

You can use the Replace count parameter to limit the number of replaces:

```
c.Value = Replace(c.Value, Mid(c.Value, 6, 3), "", 1, 1)
```

---

For the space padding, another alternative is https://stackoverflow.com/a/29541815/1383168

```
Dim s20 As String * 20
s20 = c.Value
c.Value = s20
```

or something like

```
c.Value = c.Value & Space(20 - Len(c.Value))
```

Comment: Used the replace function w/ count parameter; works great! (Thanks for the tip re:spaces, too)

Answer (score 0):

This section,

```
Do While Len(c.Value) < 20
    c.Value = c.Value & " "
Loop
```

... might be better as,

```
c = Left(c.Value2 & Space(20), 20)
```

The [Replace function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241892.aspx) has a parameter to set the maximum number of replacements made. The default is `-1` (replace all occurrences) but you can easily set it to a single replacement.

```
 c = Replace(c.Value2, transNum, vbNullString, Count:=1)
```