# listbox copy to clipboard keeping columns

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, clipboard

In my userform, the user selects some option and when they play the cmd, my listbox show the results.

Now I need to copy the listbox data do clipboard, and with this code I can do!

```
Private Sub BtnCopy_Click()
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim strList As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim MyData As DataObject

For i = 0 To Me.lbResult.ListCount - 1
    If Len(Trim(Me.lbResult.List(i))) > 0 Then ' blank values excluded here
       For iCol = 0 To lbResult.ColumnCount - 1
           strList = strList & Trim(FrmPrice.lbResult2.List(i, iCol)) & vbTab
       Next
       strList = strList & vbCrLf
    End If
Next i


Set MyData = New DataObject
MyData.Clear
MyData.SetText strList
MyData.PutInClipboard
End Sub
```

Right, but when I paste the data (into a body mail) this are the result

```
Pays    City    Cap Q.li    €_STD   €_NEW   Delta   
DE  ACHERN/BADER    DE_77   11  179,85  284,85  105
```

My goal will be to have the text into a "columns" like this:

```
Pays    City            Cap     Q.li    €_STD   €_NEW   Delta   
DE      ACHERN/BADER    DE_77   11      179,85  284,85  105
```

There are one way to copy/extract data from listbox keeping columns space?

I tried also this workaround, when I prepare the data for listbox I "set" the length

```
Private Sub btnEval_Click()

Dim tax As Long, qle As Double, spe As Double
Dim oupt(0 To 1, 0 To 6)

    Me.lbResult.Clear

oupt(0, 0) = "Pays"                         'filed lenght 4
oupt(0, 1) = "City" & String(16, " ")       'filed lenght 20
oupt(0, 2) = "Cap" & String(3, " ")         'filed lenght 6
oupt(0, 3) = "Q.li" & String(4, " ")         'filed lenght 8
oupt(0, 4) = "€_STD" & String(3, " ")         'filed lenght 8
oupt(0, 5) = "€_NEW" & String(3, " ")         'filed lenght 8
oupt(0, 6) = "Delta" & String(3, " ")         'filed lenght 8

oupt(1, 0) = cbCountry.List(cbCountry.ListIndex, 0) & String(Application.Min(4, Len(oupt(1, 0))), " ")
oupt(1, 1) = cbCity.List(cbCity.ListIndex, 0) & String(Application.Min(20, Len(oupt(1, 1))), " ")
oupt(1, 2) = cbCap.List(cbCap.ListIndex, 1) & String(Application.Min(6, Len(oupt(1, 2))), " ")
oupt(1, 3) = tax / 100 & String(Application.Min(8, Len(oupt(1, 3))), " ")
oupt(1, 4) = Application.Max(qle, spe) & String(Application.Min(8, Len(oupt(1, 4))), " ")
oupt(1, 5) = Round(Me.NewPrice2 * 1.055, 2) & String(Application.Min(8, Len(Application.Min(1, 5))), " ")
oupt(1, 6) = Round(Me.NewPrice2 * 1.055, 2) - Application.Max(qle, spe) & String(Application.Min(8, Len(oupt(1, 6))), " ")

    AddItemLb2 (oupt)

errorHandler:

End Sub

Private Sub AddItemLb(ByVal arr)
    With lbResult
        .Clear
           .AddItem
           .List = arr
        .ListIndex = -1
    End With
End Sub
```

But this aren't the correct way, the result don't change.

```
Pays    City    Cap Q.li    €_STD   €_NEW   Delta   
DE  ACHERN/BADER    DE_77   11  179,85  284,85  105
```

Thanks for any suggestions

fabrizio

Comment: `Len(oupt(1, 0))` (and all the remaining) is zero, there is no value there yet. Implement and function like this [PadRight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12060429)

Comment: Padding your values with spaces only works if you use a mono-spaced font (eg. Courirer) - otherwise (using a proportionally-spaced font) the characters are different widths and nothing will line up.

Comment: @TimWilliams right, I set font(Currier Now) into my listbox, but when I paste my clipboard the font aren't Currier!?!, Can I preserve the font format or I can assign the same as DataObject?

Comment: You'd need to set the font after pasting in the mail...