# How to create a GUID in Excel?

Tags: excel, guid

I need a function to add a GUID to cells in excel. I found [this previous question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031347/how-can-i-generate-guids-in-excel), but it is not working. It suggests the following function:

```
=CONCATENATE(DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,4294967295),8),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,6553‌​5),4),"-"
    ,DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(16384,20479),4),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(32768,49151‌​),4),"-"
    ,DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,65535),4),DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,4294967295),8))
```

I have been unable to get the concatenate method to work, and so tried it using the "&" figure to concatenate anyway. That seemed to work, but then I get an inexplicable error on the second `DEX2HEX` block: `DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,6553‌​5),4)`. The Excel formula evaluator says it's invalid, but I can't seem to figure out why at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just use the VBA code supplied in the same question?

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? AFAIK `RANDBETWEEN` was only introduced in 2007. If you use 2003, replace it with `INT(RAND()*65535)`

Comment: @PeterAlbert `but then I get an inexplicable error on the second DEX2HEX block` - assuming that 1st block is ok)

Comment: @PeterL.: Not sure I understand your comment... :-(

Comment: @PeterAlbert I suppose that means 1st block did NOT get errors, or simply `RANDBETWEEN` works fine.

Comment: @PeterL.: Ahh, I see. Stupid me, should read the question better next time... :-)

Comment: @PeterAlbert no problem) Being QA has its pros & cons..)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables tried that, it didnt' seem to work either. The function just produced a #!VALUE error.

Comment: There are illegal characters in the function you copied and pasted - see my post.

Comment: Please use rchako's solution instead, see my comment there for more info.

Comment: I suppose I don't have to point out that this doesn't generate "real" GUIDs - because they have no version number. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier for details

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I am using the following function in v.2013 excel vba macro code

```
Public Function GetGUID() As String 
    GetGUID = Mid$(CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").GUID, 2, 36) 
End Function
```

Comment: couldnt get PeterL's solution to work in Excel 2013.. and after a total of 10 seconds of debugging the function, I found your solution to be a better fit for me.  Works perfect. thanks!

Comment: This should be used instead of Frazture's answer because it is much more straightforward and relies on the system to generate the guid. Fraxture's solution (no offense) does not even create a valid guid as it doesn't take things such as the current time, MAC address, etc. into account. They also won't include the guid version bit.

Guids are not just a set of random characters, there is meaning behind them. More info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier#Algorithm

Comment: Attention: there may be problem with the library (Permission denied) after installing win update: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45082258/vba-set-typelib-createobjectscriptlet-typelib-permission-denied

Comment: I confirm @Radek 's comment that after a security update to Office, this mechanism no longer works.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45332789/575559 documents the Microsoft recommended methods to prevent the above function from causing a "permission denied" error OR to make use of an alternative function.

Comment: Declare Function CoCreateGuid Lib "ole32" (ByRef GUID As Byte) As Long
Public Function GenerateGUID() As String
    Dim ID(0 To 15) As Byte
    Dim N As Long
    Dim GUID As String
    Dim Res As Long
    Res = CoCreateGuid(ID(0))

    For N = 0 To 15
        GUID = GUID & IIf(ID(N) < 16, "0", "") & Hex$(ID(N))
        If Len(GUID) = 8 Or Len(GUID) = 13 Or Len(GUID) = 18 Or Len(GUID) = 23 Then
            GUID = GUID & "-"
        End If
    Next N
    GenerateGUID = GUID
End Function

Answer (score 114):

As of modern version of Excel, there's the syntax with commas, not semicolons. I'm posting this answer for convenience of others so they don't have to replace the strings- We're all lazy... hrmp... human, right?

> =CONCATENATE(DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,4294967295),8),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,65535),4),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,65535),4),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,65535),4),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,4294967295),8),DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,65535),4))

Or, if you like me dislike when a guid screams and shouts and you, we can go lower-cased like this.

> =LOWER(CONCATENATE(DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,4294967295),8),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,65535),4),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,65535),4),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,65535),4),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,4294967295),8),DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,65535),4)))

Comment: Comas and semicolons differs because of localization but not because of modern or not so modern Excel. However good answer

Comment: Perfect! Tested and using

Comment: I needed semicolons, i.e. `=CONCATENATE(DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0;4294967295);8);"-";DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0;42949);4);"-";DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0;42949);4);"-";DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0;42949);4);"-";DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0;4294967295);8);DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0;42949);4)) `

Comment: @Matt I think this is my highest upvoted answer ever. Kind of sad because I'm much more skilled in other techs. I'm glad for whatever I get, of course, but still...   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten - Don't misunderstand me, your answer was useful for me, and I upvoted it. Just wanted to mention that for some reasons, my Excel version wants semicolons instead of commas for separating the parameters - don't know where that can be configured (but as [trigras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2010685/trigras) mentioned, surely a localization issue). However, with commas, it won't work on my end, but with semicolons - so I thought it might be useful for some folks to put it in the comments.

Comment: @Matt I can't speak for his experience. I believe that has changes between different version but it might also depend on localization. The important thing is to remember that it's always a subject to change so one should try both this and that if it stops working. Thanks for the upvote. I do enjoy those small tickies, haha.

Comment: If believe `RANDBETWEEN(0,42949)` should be `RANDBETWEEN(0,65535)`, otherwise the four digit parts of the GUID will only be between 0000 and A7C5
, whereas they should go all the way to FFFF

Comment: @ReversedEngineer You are correct. I'm impressed partly because you noticed it and partly because no one else did in almost 5 years! I believe I started with `4294967295`, which corresponds to `16^8`, i.e. 8 consecutive `F`. Then, I picked the 4 first initial, decimal digits. My bad.

Comment: If anybody needs it on a spanish (español) Excel installation: `=CONCATENAR(DEC.A.HEX(ALEATORIO.ENTRE(0;4294967295);8);"-";DEC.A.HEX(ALEATORIO.ENTRE(0;65536);4);"-";DEC.A.HEX(ALEATORIO.ENTRE(0;65536);4);"-";DEC.A.HEX(ALEATORIO.ENTRE(0;65536);4);"-";DEC.A.HEX(ALEATORIO.ENTRE(0;4294967295);8);DEC.A.HEX(ALEATORIO.ENTRE(0;65536);4))`

Comment: Note that this is not UUID v4. The 3rd group needs to start with 4.

Comment: @GerhardPowell I'm not sure if I'm getting you correctly. Could you provide any reference to support that statement, please? As far I'm aware, there's no restrictions to what any of the defined groups consist of.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: https://www.uuidtools.com/decode

Comment: @GerhardPowell I see that the M-digit denotes version and that **may** be 4. However, it's not stated that it **should** be 4. Are you saying that the version the suggested Excel formula produces **is** 4? How can one determine that? Please help me understand.

Comment: Random UUIDs are version 4. All the versions are allocated to different purposes. http://guid.one/guid

Comment: @GerhardPowell I had no idea about that property of GUIDs. I'm humbled and amazed. Thank you very much for educating me. This was nerdily exquisite piece of knowledge.

Comment: The issue with the formula posted by the user is that there are two null characters (`CHAR(0)`) in one of the 65535 characters. See my answer below.

Comment: @Paul Is that comment addressing the answer of mine, the original question or any of the comments?

Answer (score 39):

```
=CONCATENATE(
    DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0;4294967295);8);"-";
    DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0;42949);4);"-";
    DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0;42949);4);"-";
    DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0;42949);4);"-";
    DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0;4294967295);8);
    DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0;42949);4)
)
```

Comment: Using Excel 2013 I had to replace all semi-colons with commas.

Comment: I needed to replace the ";" with "," and then everything worked out great! Thanks :)  '=CONCATENATE(DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,4294967295),8),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,42949),4),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,42949),4),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,42949),4),"-",DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,4294967295),8),DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,42949),4))'

Comment: If it walks like a GUID and talks like a GUID it's not a GUID.

Comment: Please note that this doesn't generate a valid version 4 GUID/UUID, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)
The formula in the question is perfectly fine (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12219726/729642), or look at the answers from Masud, Fredder, or nidkil.

Comment: If believe `RANDBETWEEN(0;42949)` should be `RANDBETWEEN(0;65535)`, otherwise the four digit parts of the GUID will only be between 0000 and A7C5
, whereas they should go all the way to FFFF

Answer (score 14):

```
=LOWER(
    CONCATENATE(
        DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,POWER(16,8)),8), "-", 
        DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,POWER(16,4)),4),"-","4", 
        DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,POWER(16,3)),3),"-",
        DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(8,11)),
        DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,POWER(16,3)),3),"-",
        DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,POWER(16,8)),8),
        DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0,POWER(16,4)),4)
    )
)
```

Taken from git @mobilitymaster.

Comment: I pasted this once into a cell and it seemed to work well. But then I pasted it into another cell and the first cell changed. Then I tried another cell and the first 2 cells changed... why does it do that?

Comment: That is very interesting observation, I was not aware of that. I used 'outside dragging option' in excel to generate guid in batch.  
Here is a kind of hacky and incomplete explanation, I found the function =randbetween(x,y) changes its value everytime we hit 'enter' anywhere with a new value.  
One way to stop the random generation I think is generate the guid in batch using 'outside dragging' and then copy all of them and pasting only the value.

Comment: It is due to the Automatic calculation setting on in excel. If you go into Excel Options, then Formulas, then you will see something called "Workbook Calcuation" if you disable it, it will only run the calculations when you manually press the button in the bottom pane.

Comment: WARNING: This has a random constant "4" in the middle of the formula...

Comment: @Sancarn: It generates a valid version 4 GUID/UUID, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)
(Also note the other 2 fixed bits which are forced by using RANDBETWEEN(8,11))

Comment: @SirKillALot interesting, never knew about these. Still have no idea what the point of them is... You're just increasing the likeliness of a duplicate?

Comment: @Sancarn: That's how GUID/UUIDs are defined. In the different versions all those bits and bytes have different meanings (e.g. version 3 and 5 are based on namespace hashes). Only Version 4 is meant to be random, except those couple version and variant bits to distinguish them from the other versions/variants.
                                                                           
The Wikipedia article also has en entry about collisions, which is probably correct :-), stating for version 4:
"... the probability to find a duplicate within 103 trillion version-4 UUIDs is one in a billion."

Answer (score 10):

This is not a problem with the function at all.

It took me a bit of digging, but the problem is in copying and pasting. Try copying this: `RANDBETWEEN(0,6553‌​5)` string, posted in your original question, and paste it into a Hex Editor, then you'll see that there are actually two null characters in the 65535:

```
00000000  52 41 4E 44 42 45 54 57 45 45 4E 28 30 2C 36 35  RANDBETWEEN(0,65
00000010  35 33 00 00 35 29                                53‌..​5)
```

Comment: you are the true hacker and genius here

Comment: @hongsy: Thank-you!  True appreciation  ;o)

Answer (score 3):

for me it is correct, in Excel spanish

```
=CONCATENAR(
DEC.A.HEX(ALEATORIO.ENTRE(0,4294967295),8),"-",
DEC.A.HEX(ALEATORIO.ENTRE(0,65535),4),"-",
DEC.A.HEX(ALEATORIO.ENTRE(16384,20479),4),"-",
DEC.A.HEX(ALEATORIO.ENTRE(32768,49151),4),"-",
DEC.A.HEX(ALEATORIO.ENTRE(0,65535),4),
DEC.A.HEX(ALEATORIO.ENTRE(0,4294967295),8)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The formula for Dutch Excel:

```
=KLEINE.LETTERS(
    TEKST.SAMENVOEGEN(
        DEC.N.HEX(ASELECTTUSSEN(0;MACHT(16;8));8);"-";
        DEC.N.HEX(ASELECTTUSSEN(0;MACHT(16;4));4);"-";"4";
        DEC.N.HEX(ASELECTTUSSEN(0;MACHT(16;3));3);"-";
        DEC.N.HEX(ASELECTTUSSEN(8;11));
        DEC.N.HEX(ASELECTTUSSEN(0;MACHT(16;3));3);"-";
        DEC.N.HEX(ASELECTTUSSEN(0;MACHT(16;8));8);
        DEC.N.HEX(ASELECTTUSSEN(0;MACHT(16;4));4)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The formula for French Excel:

```
=CONCATENER(
DECHEX(ALEA.ENTRE.BORNES(0;4294967295);8);"-";
DECHEX(ALEA.ENTRE.BORNES(0;42949);4);"-";
DECHEX(ALEA.ENTRE.BORNES(0;42949);4);"-";
DECHEX(ALEA.ENTRE.BORNES(0;42949);4);"-";
DECHEX(ALEA.ENTRE.BORNES(0;4294967295);8);
DECHEX(ALEA.ENTRE.BORNES(0;42949);4))
```

As noted by Josh M, this does not provide a compliant GUID however, but this works well for my current need.

Comment: For a compliant one see the formula in the actual question, or look at the answers from Masud, Fredder, or nidkil.

Answer (score 0):

The formula for German Excel:

```
=KLEIN(
    VERKETTEN(
        DEZINHEX(ZUFALLSBEREICH(0;POTENZ(16;8));8);"-";
        DEZINHEX(ZUFALLSBEREICH(0;POTENZ(16;4));4);"-";"4";
        DEZINHEX(ZUFALLSBEREICH(0;POTENZ(16;3));3);"-";
        DEZINHEX(ZUFALLSBEREICH(8;11));
        DEZINHEX(ZUFALLSBEREICH(0;POTENZ(16;3));3);"-";
        DEZINHEX(ZUFALLSBEREICH(0;POTENZ(16;8));8);
        DEZINHEX(ZUFALLSBEREICH(0;POTENZ(16;4));
    )
)
```

Comment: You may be missing closing brackets `)` on this one.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a number of options and running into various issue with newer versions of Excel (2016) I came across this post from MS that worked like a charm.  I enhanced it bit using some code from a post by danwagner.co

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CoCreateGuid Lib "ole32.dll" (Guid As GUID_TYPE) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function StringFromGUID2 Lib "ole32.dll" (Guid As GUID_TYPE, ByVal lpStrGuid As LongPtr, ByVal cbMax As Long) As LongPtr

Function CreateGuidString(Optional IncludeHyphens As Boolean = True, Optional IncludeBraces As Boolean = False)
    Dim Guid As GUID_TYPE
    Dim strGuid As String
    Dim retValue As LongPtr

    Const guidLength As Long = 39 'registry GUID format with null terminator {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}

    retValue = CoCreateGuid(Guid)

    If retValue = 0 Then
        strGuid = String$(guidLength, vbNullChar)
        retValue = StringFromGUID2(Guid, StrPtr(strGuid), guidLength)

        If retValue = guidLength Then
            '   valid GUID as a string
            '   remove them from the GUID
            If Not IncludeHyphens Then
                strGuid = Replace(strGuid, "-", vbNullString, Compare:=vbTextCompare)
            End If

            '   If IncludeBraces is switched from the default False to True,
            '   leave those curly braces be!
            If Not IncludeBraces Then
                strGuid = Replace(strGuid, "{", vbNullString, Compare:=vbTextCompare)
                strGuid = Replace(strGuid, "}", vbNullString, Compare:=vbTextCompare)
            End If


            CreateGuidString = strGuid
        End If
    End If

End Function


Public Sub TestCreateGUID()
    Dim Guid As String
    Guid = CreateGuidString() '<~ default
    Debug.Print Guid
End Sub
```

There are additional options in the original MS post found here:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-msoffice_custom-mso_2010/guid-run-time-error-70-permission-denied/c9ee4076-98af-4032-bc87-40ad7aa7cb38

Comment: If I try this I get the error: User defined type not declared (Windows 10, Excel 2019)

Comment: @habakuk This needs the definition for `GUID_TYPE` from the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ken Thompson is right! - for me also this way works (excel 2016), but type definition GUID_TYPE is skipped, so full scripting is:

```
Private Type GUID_TYPE
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(7) As Byte
End Type

Private Declare PtrSafe Function CoCreateGuid Lib "ole32.dll" (Guid As GUID_TYPE) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function StringFromGUID2 Lib "ole32.dll" (Guid As GUID_TYPE, ByVal lpStrGuid As LongPtr, ByVal cbMax As Long) As LongPtr

Function CreateGuidString(Optional IncludeHyphens As Boolean = True, Optional IncludeBraces As Boolean = False)
    Dim Guid As GUID_TYPE
    Dim strGuid As String
    Dim retValue As LongPtr

    Const guidLength As Long = 39 'registry GUID format with null terminator {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}

    retValue = CoCreateGuid(Guid)

    If retValue = 0 Then
        strGuid = String$(guidLength, vbNullChar)
        retValue = StringFromGUID2(Guid, StrPtr(strGuid), guidLength)

        If retValue = guidLength Then
            '   valid GUID as a string
            '   remove them from the GUID
            If Not IncludeHyphens Then
                strGuid = Replace(strGuid, "-", vbNullString, Compare:=vbTextCompare)
            End If

            '   If IncludeBraces is switched from the default False to True,
            '   leave those curly braces be!
            If Not IncludeBraces Then
                strGuid = Replace(strGuid, "{", vbNullString, Compare:=vbTextCompare)
                strGuid = Replace(strGuid, "}", vbNullString, Compare:=vbTextCompare)
            End If


            CreateGuidString = strGuid
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

The formula for Polish version:

```
=ZŁĄCZ.TEKSTY(
    DZIES.NA.SZESN(LOS.ZAKR(0;4294967295);8);"-";
    DZIES.NA.SZESN(LOS.ZAKR(0;42949);4);"-";
    DZIES.NA.SZESN(LOS.ZAKR(0;42949);4);"-";
    DZIES.NA.SZESN(LOS.ZAKR(0;42949);4);"-";
    DZIES.NA.SZESN(LOS.ZAKR(0;4294967295);8);
    DZIES.NA.SZESN(LOS.ZAKR(0;42949);4)
)
```

Comment: Please note that this doesn't generate a valid version 4 GUID/UUID, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)
The formula in the question is perfectly fine (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12219726/729642), or look at the answers from Masud, Fredder, or nidkil.

Answer (score -3):

**Italian** version:

```
=CONCATENA(
    DECIMALE.HEX(CASUALE.TRA(0;4294967295);8);"-";
    DECIMALE.HEX(CASUALE.TRA(0;42949);4);"-";
    DECIMALE.HEX(CASUALE.TRA(0;42949);4);"-";
    DECIMALE.HEX(CASUALE.TRA(0;42949);4);"-";
    DECIMALE.HEX(CASUALE.TRA(0;4294967295);8);
    DECIMALE.HEX(CASUALE.TRA(0;42949);4))
```

Comment: Please note that this doesn't generate a valid version 4 GUID/UUID, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)
The formula in the question is perfectly fine (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12219726/729642), or look at the answers from Masud, Fredder, or nidkil.

Answer (score -3):

ESP:

```
=CONCATENAR(
    DEC.A.HEX(ALEATORIO.ENTRE(0;4294967295);8);"-"; 
    DEC.A.HEX(ALEATORIO.ENTRE(0;42949);4);"-"; 
    DEC.A.HEX(ALEATORIO.ENTRE(0;42949);4);"-"; 
    DEC.A.HEX(ALEATORIO.ENTRE(0;42949);4);"-"; 
    DEC.A.HEX(ALEATORIO.ENTRE(0;4294967295);8); 
    DEC.A.HEX(ALEATORIO.ENTRE(0;42949);4)
)
```

Comment: Please note that this doesn't generate a valid version 4 GUID/UUID, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)
The formula in the question is perfectly fine (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12219726/729642), or look at the answers from Masud, Fredder, or nidkil.