# VBA 'set typelib = createobject(“scriptlet.typelib”)' Permission Denied - same problem, new reason?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-office

In 2017 this problem was described

```
createobject(“scriptlet.typelib”)' Permission Denied
```

[VBA 'set typelib = createobject("scriptlet.typelib")' Permission Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45082258/vba-set-typelib-createobjectscriptlet-typelib-permission-denied)

At that time the problem could be solved by removing KB3213624.
Now October 2018, the problem happens again even if KB3213624 is not installed.

Yesterday about 30 updates were installed on a PC with that problem. It will take me a long time to check them one by one.
Does anybody else have the same experience and knows already which update is to blame this time?

Comment: I guess you will have to adopt - _resistance is futile_: [Workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332357/ms-access-vba-error-run-time-error-70-permission-denied)