# E_ACCESSDENIED "General Access denied error" /CreateObject("Vbscript") blocked under office 365 VBA environment

Tags: vba, vbscript, office365, createobject

I have recently encountered an issue running code within Access 2016 and for office 365.  Our COM component that we authored stopped working with the newer versions of office.  I was able to attach the debugger and confirmed that trying to create an instance of VBScript INSIDE of VBA (our COM object uses Vbscript internally to execute code on our projects called via Access VBA ) returns E_ACCESSDENIED when CoCreateInstance is called inside of our COM object.  Previous versions of Office as late as 2013 this worked just fine.

Also if you just run:

```
Dim tst As Object
Set tst = CreateObject("VBScript")
If Not (tst Is Nothing) Then
    MsgBox "good"
Else
    MsgBox "Bad"
End IF
```

In Excel or Access VBA on anything greater than 2013 I get:
"Run-time error '70': Permission denied" on the CreateObject("VBScript") line
[VBScript CreateObject error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd4Go.png)

This code executed just fine for me under office 2013 as well.

I have tried the following:

1. Setting ActiveX settings to enable all ( Under "Tust Center" )
2. Enable all Macros ( Under "Tust Center" )
3. Disabled "sandbox" at all times using the instructions listed here:
   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-sandbox-mode-on-or-off-to-disable-macros-8cc7bad8-38c2-4a7a-a604-43e9a7bbc4fb

Does anyone know if there is a setting of some sort I can change in office to allow a vbscript instance to be instantiated from within office 365 VBA environment?
I have searched for a similar issue on the web and so far have found nothing useful.

Comment: also maybe look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45082258/vba-set-typelib-createobjectscriptlet-typelib-permission-denied

Comment: YES! Thank you so much! I knew there was something in office restricting the creation I just had absolutely NO clue where to find it!  Thank you sous2817!

Answer (score 1):

So Thanks to sous2817 I was able to find actually what it was that I needed.  While it may not be the most secure approach in all cases it should work for me.
I also found these 2 links that I used once I was pointed in the right direction:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/security-settings-for-com-objects-in-office-b08a031c-0ab8-3796-b8ec-a89f9dbb443d

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/updates/control-block-ole-com

Basically I had to make an exception to prevent MS Office from blocking VBScript.