# How to get the Application.ProductCode in office for mac

Tags: macos, excel, ms-office, vba

I am building a small Excel VBA app where I would need to access the Application.ProductCode property. There is no problems on Windows, however I would need this script to also run on Excel for Mac, and there it seems that this property is not accessible. I receive the error message

"run time error '438':
Object doesn't support this property or method"

Does someone know a way to get access to this property in the VBA scripts?

Would there be maybe a way to access this information using the new excel javascript addins? I checked but I could not access this information.

Thanks for your help

Mikhail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has already been answered, if I'm understanding the intent of your question correctly:

[How can I generate GUIDs in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031347/how-can-i-generate-guids-in-excel)

and you'll see the comment:

"Works perfectly on Excel for Mac, just have to change ; to , – Mirko Akov"